# Loading and deleting js when certain events occur

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, load

I want to load a specific js file when a `.mouseenter()` event occurs. When the `.mouseleave()` event occurs, I want to cancel the load js when `.mouseenter()` is done.

I do not know how to approach it. 
I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: You can append the script tag and remove it, or just change the `src`. Unless the `.js` file is huge, though, I recommend you just load it when the page loads.

Comment: Why would you want to load a file? Try using a loop, with a break condition (so it can exit when the mouse leaves). If you host this on a website, and a user has bad connection speed, if the user mouses over quickly, the file may not even load in time.

Comment: I extracted the canvas file from Adobe Animation CC, so I need to have three canvas in one html file. When three canvas are running at the same time, the web becomes too slow. So when the mouse enters the div, only one js file will be loaded.